# Pygame Import Error, Python 3.2

Tags: python, pygame

I'm having an issue with the Pygame module. I run Python 3.2 and installed the respective Pygame file, but now when I try to import it in the IDLE, it gives me this error:

```
>>> import pygame
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#0>", line 1, in <module>
    import pygame
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\pygame\__init__.py", line 95, in <module>
    from pygame.base import *
ImportError: DLL load failed: %1 is not a valid Win32 application.
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: What exactly did you download? Did you use the EXE? If so, are you sure you took the right one, matching your system specifications etc.?

Answer (score 1):

According to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4676433/solving-dll-load-failed-1-is-not-a-valid-win32-application-for-pygame) about the same error, the issue is likely that you have a 64-bit version of Python installed, and a 32-bit version of Pygame.  I don't think Pygame has any 64-bit versions available, so to fix your problem you will have to download a 32-bit version of Python.